# What sans-serif font is used in this image ("Uniform Center")

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

[image]

Can any one find me what font is used here . I searched for it everywhere but cant find it .

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! Please edit your question and let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increases. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font Name : Serpentine

[Available on MyFonts.](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/serpentine/)

[image]

Comment: It is pretty close, but to me it does not look like a perfect match.

Comment: you can select from here http://www.abstractfonts.com/search/similar+to+serpentine

Comment: I can't verify if the freebie font site links were legit, so linking to MyFonts (lots of freebie font sites are of questionable sources)

Comment: And it's true it's not an exact match to the OP, though I have a hunch the original logo is Serpentine 'squooshed'.

Comment: +1 for use of the industry-specific professional term of 'squooshed'